# Ubuntu/Linux version recommendation for HP dv6 3122TX?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers

I purchased a HP dv6 3122TX recently and after installing Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit I ran into multiple issues like,

- The wireless driver is not supported by Uubntu. ([1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1600498))
  [The driver is RaLink RT3090 ]
- The ethernet stopped working sometimes for no reason [The driver is Realtek RTL8111/8168B ]
- "Corrupted low memory at ..." issue which is described as a kernel bug in Ubuntu support forums. (It started to take me to a terminal instead of the GUI and couldn't start x server after that)

As I'm not an expert Ubuntu user I got fed up of all these issue and got back to Windows 7. But I need an Ubuntu installation up and running for my development work.

What are your suggestions about a reasonable Ubuntu version that I should try? Or a different Linux variation? Should I stick to a 32-bit version?

It'd be great anyone can give some advice on this issue.

Comment: Have you considered running ubuntu in a VM instead? I have unbuntu happily running in virtualbox.

Comment: I hardly use Windows usually. So in my case it's going to be ideal if I could install Ubuntu. That's why I'm trying hard to get an installation running without any issues.

Comment: This isn't really a great question for the site :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The wireless driver is not supported by Uubntu. (1) [The driver is RaLink RT3090 ]
```

It is supported - you can load any windows driver via option called NDIS if system update does not get drivers right

```
The ethernet stopped working sometimes for no reason [The driver is Realtek RTL8111/8168B ]
```

Cable unplugged?

```
"Corrupted low memory at ..." issue which is described as a kernel bug
```

It is a BIOS bug and such message says BIOS is buggy and your day is saved

```
 As I'm not an expert Ubuntu user I got fed up of all these issue and got back to Windows 7. But I need an Ubuntu installation up and running for my development work.
```

Install Virtualbox or vmware player and install 32 or 64bit ubuntu from ISO image. Your CPU supports Virtualisation well.

```
What are your suggestions about a reasonable Ubuntu version that I should try?
```

No idea - Ubuntu is a graphic shell over debian, just like Mint.

```
Or a different Linux variation?
```

[Yes](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/10-best-linux-distros-for-2011-704584) [yes](http://distrowatch.com)

```
Should I stick to a 32-bit version?
```

64bit version implies better memory protection and may be a better test, it also supports systems with 3 or more GB of RAM better(32bit would waste a gigabyte or  less under 4GB) . Virtualised you can have both.... 64bit ca run 32bit programms at good speed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Archlinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) or if you can afford the time, [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org).

Also you can always try installing the [zen-kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZenKernel) on Ubuntu, might be better than the stock kernel.

Comment: The page you linked for zen-kernel (on ubuntu wiki) is deprecated, and my quick glance over gave heaps of stuff that's just wrong in it.

Comment: I have since moved to Arch and started using ck instead of zen. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux-ck